# Добавляю в layout Элементы но они не отображаются. С чем это связанно? Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, layout

Здесь не отображается текст "Обо мне:" и голубая форма. как это исправить? Скажите пожалуйста. Заранее Спасибо[image: Вот Здесь не отображается текст "Обо мне:" и голубая форма]

Comment: Рекомендую отказаться от использования RelativeLayout и больше никогда им не пользоваться) Это двухпроходной компонент, очень долго рендерится. Используйте ConstraintLayout

Comment: И если хотите, чтоб вам помогли, приложите код разметки

Comment: Учту) Спасибо. Но это не помогло

Comment: Блииин вот я тупой. Всё понял. Оказывается я в normal формате не указал элементы